# What is the purpose of IJobHostContextFactory/JobHostContextFactory?

Tags: c#, azure-functions, dotnet-isolated

We are in the process of migrating Azure Functions to isolated in our project. During this process I came across an implementation of `Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.IJobHostContextFactory`. But no one could tell me what it is needed for.

I haven't found any documentation for it. Can anyone of you help me?

What is the purpose of `Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.IJobHostContextFactory` or its implementation `Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.JobHostContextFactory`?

Do I need it for isolated functions?

---

Edit:

I looked into it again and found that when I start an In-Process function the ServiceCollection contains a reference to IJobHostContextFactory. However, when I start an isolated function, the ServiceCollection does not contain a reference. That is, for isolated functions, the JobHostContextFactory does not seem to be needed.

Comment: Please mark Dai's answer as correct (if it helped you understand the `IJobHostContextFactory`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's an interface that passes the *Ronseal challenge*: ("[it does exactly what it says on the tin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Does_exactly_what_it_says_on_the_tin)"): it creates instances of `JobHostContext` objects, which are used/consumed by `IFunctionInstance` objects which represent your *functions*.

You can see this in the source-code of `JobHost` available here: https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host/JobHost.cs

As it's a service interface *and* default implementation that's built-in to the WebJobs SDK you don't need to implement it yourself - unless you *really* need to customize how `JobHostContext` objects are created for some reason (e.g. if you're using a DI system that's not compatible with `Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection`, I guess).

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer. Can you also answer whether I need this for Isolated Functions?

Comment: How are you using it right now?